# Exibir um pdf no html, como uma imagem

Tags: html, jquery, pdf

Tenho um campo input file, que busca um pdf no computador do cliente, e gostaria de exibi-lo como se fosse uma imagem no html, estou tentando fazer isso, mas não estou achando um elemento que eu consiga adicionar o caminho do pdf e exibi-lo, todos os exemplos que vi na internet, são com URLs, e nesse caso, eu precisaria para um arquivo no computador do usuário, alguém sabe uma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta, não terá como fazer isto, pegar a imagem e renderiza-la diretamente no navegador. O que vc terá que fazer é pelo input pegar o arquivo pdf, manda-lo para um servidor e através de uma url renderizar a imagem em uma div ou em um iframe que seja.

Comment: obg amigo, achei q eu conseguiria exibi-lo igual a uma imagem, mas entao nao tem como mesmo... muitooo obggg pela resposta.. agradeco imensamente

Comment: Não sei qual o contexto da sua aplicação aí, mas, da para vc utilizar um plugin jQuery para visualizar pdf, aí quando o cara manda um arquivo no input ele pode visualiza-lo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921052/parsing-pdf-pages-as-javascript-images Tem como renderizar no canvas usando isso

Comment: @Sveen muito obg, vou tentar fazer com o canvas, e te respondo se deu certo.